# Why using jupyter notebook in python?

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I want to learn NLP with python,I have some questions

1. what ide is better?
2. what is jupyter notebook and why every tutorial use this? (should i use this as ide for python)
3. what package is better for persian language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For python IDE, I use [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/?fromMenu). If you are a student or a teacher, you can use the professional version for free, details are [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/).
2. jupyter notebook enable you to learn code more easily. You can segment your code to deferent part and run whichever part whenever and see the output. This makes you learn new things more easily. At least I think so and I am using it this way. Whenever I am learning a new python tool, I use jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter notebooks / Jupyter lab is used for it's interactive capability and the benefit of being able to mix code and documentation. Plus you can do inline visualisations and see what your data looks like.

It is used for iterative development, you should use this for exploratory data analysis and experimentation, but still use a full featured IDE for any other coding, including translating your notebooks (when complete) if you intend to run them in some sort of production environment